# when importing saves in DA:O to DA2

Tags: dragon-age-origins, dragon-age-2

When im importing save from DA:O(even had other 3 "major" DLC's) there are some inconsistency in story. is there intentionally or another bug the dragon age has? for examples:

1. it says in the import page in DA2 that Alistair was king, but im perfectly sure that i made them (Alistar and the hot widow of Cailan) ruler of Ferelden.
2. i instead got the Fool's Gold quest instead of Finding Nathaniel. im pretty sure he survived the last mission.

Please ease my mind with this questions.

Comment: for question 1, the ruler is the King!

Comment: Many of the Bioware ARPGs have bugs in the flags for their save states, and DA:O is definitely one of them (as are the Mass Effect games). You could use a save editor to 'correct' the flags to more accurately reflect which actions you took throughout the game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are known bugs in the imports from DAO to DAII, so as JonK said you can use a save editor to correct these.

1. The "hot widow" is called Anora. If you had her marry Alistair, making them both rulers of a KINGDOM, that means they are king and queen. So Alistair is the king. (He alone has a cameo, whether or not he is married to Anora. She does not appear in DAII.)
2. The Dragon Age wiki says "If you import your playthrough into Dragon Age II, the game will consider Nathaniel dead, unless he comes with you [to Amaranthine] or you save the keep, regardless of upgrades." (on the 'Epilogue (Awakening)' page)

Comment: for 2. i did save Amaranthine but made sure the keep was fully upgraded. something about the "something knights" was produced in the process.

Comment: I did more research on the Dragon Age wiki, and updated my answer to reflect this. It seems Nathaniel is bugged if you go to Amaranthing and leave him in the Keep.